# Error response from daemon: No such image: xxxxxxxxx

Tags: docker

I am trying to save a "snapshot" of my docker container to move it to another host. However, I tried a few methods of saving the container and I don't see to be able to get it saved. Do the container need to be stopped or can it be running while I run this code? `docker save my_container > my_container.tar`

I am getting this error after running `docker save my_container > my_container.tar` Please advise.
[image]

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting pictures of error messages.

Comment: are you trying with container id or image id? If you are using docker save then please ensure it is <imageid> and not the container Id.  Also if you wish to save the entire docker container, we can use the docker export and import command to save the docker container. Please try. Thank you

Comment: You'd never do this, any more than you'd try to transport an individual process to the other system.  `docker run` a new container from the same image on the other host.